# To check for special characters in a string

Tags: powershell

I need to find special character in a string which has alphanumeric values in it.

I have tried the below code snippet but it doesn't work.

```
$Special_characters = ('\n|\r|\t|\a|\"|\`')
$Value = "g63evsy3swisnwhd83bs3hs9sn329hs\t"
if($Value -match $Special_characters)
{
    Write-Host "Special characters are present"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "special characters are absent"
}
```

The output says "special characters are absent" even though there are special characters at the end. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an one-liner:

```
$Special_characters = '\n|\r|\t|\a|\"|\`'
$Value = "g63evsy3swisnwhd83bs3hs9sn329hs\t"

$result = @($Special_characters -split '\|' | % { $Value.Contains( $_ ) }).Contains( $true )
```

$result is true when a special character is found, otherwise false.

Comment: the solution works. I have a doubt here $result has a null valued expression if there are no special characters and we receive an error warning and it would pose an issue while execution due to warning. Is there any way to mitigate this issue like assigning Boolean value to $result instead of null valued expression

Comment: I've updated my code, now you always get true or false.

Answer (score 1):

`$Special_Characters` here is a string, so your code is searching for the whole word (\n|\r|\t|\a|\"|`) to be found in `$Value`, which is not found.

Instead of string, you have to use array as follows:

```
$Value = "g63evsy3swisnwhd83bs3hs9sn329hs\t"
$Special_Characters = @('\\n','\\r','\\t','\\a','\\"','\\`')
$Special_Characters | Foreach-Object {
    if ($Value -match $_) {
        "$_ is present"
    } else {
        "$_ is not present"
    }
}
```

**Note**

You have to put double back-slash (\\) because backslash is considered as escape character in Powershell; Look [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html#backslash) for further information about backslash in Powershell

Comment: even after using the array, the output is Special characters are absent when in actual they are present

Comment: you have to iterate over each item in the array, I'll update the code

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding here.
The backslash is used to define a special character in a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), as e.g. `\t` define a tab.
But this is not the case for PowerShell. To define a special character in PowerShell you need to use the backtick character (See: [About Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6#long-description)), e.g. a Tab is written as `` `t ``.

In other words, the regular expression pattern in the question is correct but the input string is not (*in contrast to what the question/title suggests, there is in fact no **special character** in the given input string*").
it should be:

```
"...hs9sn329hs`t" -match '\n|\r|\t|\a|\"|\`'
True
```

As it concerns a list of single (special) characters, you might also consider a bracket expression (rather than an **`OR`** "pipe" character) for this:

```
"...hs9sn329hs`t" -match '[\n\r\t\a\"\`]'
True
```

Visa versa: it is allowed to use special characters in a regular expression pattern using [double quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#single-and-double-quoted-strings) so that PowerShell will evaluate the string (but I recommend against this):

```
"...hs9sn329hs`t" -match "`n|`r|`t|`a|`"|``"
True
```

If the input string in the question is really the string you want to check upon (implying that you refer to the backslash as a special character, which formally is not), you want to check for a `\t` rather than a **tab**,. For this you will need to escape the backslashes in your regular expression to literally match the `\t`:

```
"...hs9sn329hs\t" -match '\\n|\\r|\\t|\\a|\\"|\\`'
True
```

Comment: Nice solution omitting any `Foreach-Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the special characters you referred to.  You can try out a string by itself just to see if it works.  It must be double quoted.

```
PS /Users/js> "`n`r`t`a`"``"

    "`
```

You can also try out the -match operator by itself.

```
PS /Users/js> "`n`r`t`a`"``" -match '\n|\r|\t|\a|\"|\`'
True
```

About special characters:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer (especially were it differs from the already given answers).